# o que deu errado nesse algoritmo de backtracking?

Tags: c, recursão

Existem outras funções que geram o labirinto, verificam se o movimento é válido por ex
O único objetivo da nova função é resolvê-lo recebendo uma struct que contém: posição x e y da casa inicial (marcada com I), posição x e y da casa destino (marcada como F), a matriz de duas dimensões que contém o labirinto em si. No labirinto, as paredes que circulam o labirinto e paredes geradas pelo programa aleatoriamente são marcadas com '#', é necessário marcar o caminho feito com '.'.

Inicialmente eu fiz o programa apenas com if else e funcionou, mas quando tentei refazer com loops e as dicas passadas pelo próprio exercício, o programa não rodou e apareceu "Exit status -1". Acredito que ele está em loop infinito, mas não entendi o porquê, pois ele tem explicitado as tentativas, return false se der errado e o caso se for encontrada a saída.

```
/*função que recebe o labirinto, a posição x, a posição y e (x,y) da casa inicial e realiza a tentativa e erro*/
bool resolveLabirintoAux(LABIRINTO lab, int x, int y){
   int varX[] = {1,0,0,-1};
   int varY[] = {0,-1,1,0};
   //caso achamos o fim
   if (lab.labirinto[x][y] == 'F'){return true;}

   //tentativas: verifica se é possível usar essa posição
   if (valido(lab,x,y)){
     //troca I para E para que nao se passe em cima dessa casa de novo ou marca o que andou
     if (lab.labirinto[lab.inicioX][lab.inicioY] == 'I'){
       lab.labirinto[lab.inicioX][lab.inicioY] = 'E';}
     else{
       lab.labirinto[lab.inicioX][lab.inicioY] = '.';}
     
     // Inicia tentativa de movimento
     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
       if (resolveLabirintoAux(lab, x + varX[i], y + varY[i])){return true;}
    }
  }
    //erro: Se não conseguir, não há saída, então desmarca
    if (lab.labirinto[lab.inicioX][lab.inicioY] != 'E'){
      lab.labirinto[lab.inicioX][lab.inicioY] = ' ';}
  
    return false;
}

bool resolveLabirinto(LABIRINTO lab){
      int iniX = lab.inicioX; //salva a posição inicial de X
      int iniY = lab.inicioY; //salva a posição inicial de Y
      if (resolveLabirintoAux(lab, lab.inicioX, lab.inicioY)==false){
        lab.labirinto[iniX][iniY] = 'I' ; 
        return false;
      }
      else{
        lab.labirinto[iniX][iniY] = 'I'; 
        return true;
      }
}
```

Comment: boli-thecake , por favor , se você puder , poste o restante do código ,      parece interessante ,  e também para que alguém possa te ajudar .